# How to divde a float64 number by Timedelta in Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'rate': [np.nan, 28, 33],'tvalue':['2018-01-22','2018-03-04','2018-05-08']})
```

I  diff the tvalue  used

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

f=lambda x :datetime(*[int(item) for item in x.split('-')])    
data['tvalue'] = [f(x) for x in data['tvalue']]
data['delta'] = data['tvalue'] - data['tvalue'].shift()
```

I get this dataframe:

```
    rate     tvalue    delta
0    NaN  2018-01-22      NaT
1   28.0  2018-03-04  41 days
2   33.0  2018-05-08  65 days
```

I want to divide column `rate` by `delta`

```
 data['rate']/data['delta']
```

It is get this errors:`TypeError: ufunc true_divide cannot use operands with types dtype('float64') and dtype('<m8[ns]')`, How do I transfer timedelta type `41 days` , `65 days` , `NaT` to `41` ,`65` , `NaN`. And divide it get a solution?

Comment: `df.rate / data.delta.dt.days`

Comment: Thank a lot it work prefect , and what is dt represent ?

Comment: It's called a "datetime accessor", use it to access these datetime/timedelta attributes.